# MySQLdb raises “execute() first” error

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7

MySQLdb raises `execute() first` error.

How do I fix it?

```
    def update_query_extendNum(cls,params):
        print params
        sqlString = "REPLACE INTO editor_query(id,extend_num) values(%s,%s)"
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.executemany(sqlString,params)

        querys = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()
        return querys
```

Error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 39, in inner response = get_response(request)  
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)  
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response  response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)  
File "C:\work\test\editor\chat_test_service\editor\api.py", line 162, in updataTask  update_query = QueryService.update_query_extendNum([('02f0698462344c9299a93fea2d97b34e',11),('0350d8dcb58e48448f6d9fbabc06a43c',111)])  
File "C:\work\test\editor\chat_test_service\editor\service.py", line 58, in update_query_extendNum  return dao.QueryDao.update_query_extendNum(params)  
File "C:\work\test\editor\chat_test_service\editor\dao.py", line 109, in update_query_extendNum querys = cursor.fetchall()   
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 101, in inner return func(*args, **kwargs)  
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__  six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)  
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 101, in inner return func(*args, **kwargs)  
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQL`enter code here`db\cursors.py", line 382, in fetchall self._check_executed()  
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 105, in _check_executed self.errorhandler(self, ProgrammingError, "execute() first")  
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler raise errorclass, errorvalue ProgrammingError: execute() first
```

Comment: please learn how to format your code: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: thank you very much